# Confused about the usage of Dropbox API

Tags: java, dropbox, dropbox-api

I was implementing the new DropBox Core API in my application. I successfully created the App in Dropbox and have successfully able to download and upload files from local machine to Dropbox.

My confusion is, is this API is application specific or User level specific; meaning, if we have created the Dropbox app from account lets say A, we are able to upload files to that account after authenticating with this account credentials. When I try with another account, say B and authenticate with B's credentials(which is asked). Then files should be uploaded to A's account(App creator account) or B's account?

Hope i make my confusion clear..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. Your app account is a way where Dropbox can allow any client applications to access the Dropbox APIs.

That said, when other users install your application, authorize/login to the app, they will make requests by using their own credentials, and your App API key. Your app API key is a way for Dropbox to know that which application is sending the request.

But, the files, and other APIs will be executed with the user's credentials. So, the user's files will be uploaded to the user's account, and not to the account of your App.

So, it's both, User specific + Application Specific.